# Custom title with image

Tags: android, window, titlebar

i'm creating custom title for activity by disabling standard one and managing everything myself. I wonder if it's possible to replace/theme standart title to my needs.

I can customize size, background image, and text via themes by changing windowXYZStyle items.

The only thing i couldn't find - how i can add image instead of text.
I've tried `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE)`
and assign custom layout - but it doesn't seems to work.

EDIT : Here is a report of testing suggestions, code is below - result - image view is not showing up.

Activity

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    }
}

XML :

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/titlebar_bg"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center"
>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/title_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's possible to set your own custom title layout, however the order of execution matters.  You must do things in this order:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.my_custom_title);
```

Additionally, you may need to increase the size of the title; if you don't, then the bottom of your custom layout may just be covered up by your Activity.  You can change the size by adding a theme that specifies the title's size.  This would go into a values XML file:

```
<resources>
    <style name="LargeTitleTheme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">40dip</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then you'd need to set the theme for your Activity (or Application, if you want the entire application to have this custom title bar) in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MyCustomTitleActivity" android:theme="@style/LargeTitleTheme" />
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for reply, i've did that before asking the question. It was late - so i might messed something up. Did you try this ? Try  it in activity that extends PreferencesActivity and my_custom_title have a custom background and logo (as image view ) on it - for me it did assign custom title and text views did show up - image view in my_custom_title - didn't. Same goes for background - which can be solved by adding one more item to the LargeTitleTheme.

Comment: I've done exactly what I outlined above (I took the example code from my source).  However, I've never tried it on a PreferencesActivity before; perhaps there is some more that you must do to override that title bar.  I am not sure I understand what your issue is now though; restate?

Comment: the issue is that image view is not showing up in the custom title. And i need slap an image with logo on it instead of text.

Comment: It definitely works for a PreferenceActivity too; I believe you have to request the window feature before the call to `super.onCreate`.

Comment: i'll give it a try and report back

Comment: Daniel, Christopher please take a look at edit - image view not showing up - what the hell i'm missing , apart from brain cell ?

Comment: Please update to mention that super.onCreate() should be called after setFeatureInt. This caused my title bar to be blank many a time.

Comment: this works but it is quite not encapsulated. I mean we must modify codes at three places: activity, style and manifest.

Comment: You forget about main settings. Hw do I make custom titlebar work with it? addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

Answer (score 7):

You could always use:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

And then create your own title bar inside your Activity's View.

Comment: Yeah that exactly what i'm doing now. I was thinking that there is a way to theme standard. 
For example title bar in preference activity. I really don't want to mess with custom layouts just for the sake of the title bar.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this might be the best option. For a start, it would avoid the title bar flicker when the application opens as well as the hackish workaround I needed to use to remove the margins from the containing layer, so that I wouldn't see a grey border around the title bar.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you need to use an image in the title rather than just combining it as part of your background image and leaving the title blank? Using a [NinePatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html) image I would expect that you would be able to achieve a result that would look good on regardless of the device?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following code to fit my custom title to the screen

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header_img"
    android:src="@drawable/header_img"
    android:layout_width="700dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip" />
```