# How to customize the top status bar in an Android app?

Tags: android, colors, themes, statusbar, skin

Specifically I want to change the text and background colors. Is it possible to change the colors of the 'animated progress wheel' too? Can I use a theme to do this? Can anyone point me to an example theme I can look at?

Comment: Actually this is possible in an application to be done system-wide. See my application StatusBar+ on the Android Market and GitHub https://github.com/Tombarr/StatusBar-.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can use a custom view for the app's title bar.  See the answers to this question:  [Custom title with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086989/custom-title-with-image)

Answer (score 2):

If by "top status bar" you mean where the battery meter and signal meter and notifications go, you cannot change it from an app. You can set a theme to remove it (e.g., `Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`). This is usually used for applications that truly need the full screen, such as video players and some games.

Comment: I think he's talking about the TitleBar not the StatusBar, since he mentions the 'progress wheel'.

Comment: Yes, I meant the title bar. Thanks.