# How to make customized status bar (having 3G,signals, Battery,time) in android and the status bar will place in bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to make custom status bar and placed in the bottom of the android screen.. I am new to android developing..... please any one guide me.....customized status bar should be appear at lancher screen (Home screen)...... please any one guide me.....

Thank you In advance.

Comment: duplicate question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494787/how-to-customize-the-top-status-bar-in-an-android-app

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change progress bar's progress color in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your theme to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

and just draw new title bar on screen using canvas etc.

or just use

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.my_custom_title);
```

Comment: yes you are right Ruuhkis...I want to make custom status bar and placed in the bottom of the android screen.. I am new to android developing..... please any one guide me.....customized status bar should be appear at lancher screen (Home screen).....plz guide me any one

Comment: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.my_custom_title);