# Display custom title bar for Android with XML

Tags: xml, android

In Android documentation describing "[Configuring General Window Properties](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#configurewindowproperties)", it is suggested that specifying properties via XML is preferable whenever possible to avoid seeing the title bar flash. As an example, instead of setting `Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE` with requestWindowFeature, they set it to `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar`. Is there a similar way to set a custom title bar to be used in the XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete set of XML attributes available is documented in [R.styleable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html). There does not appear to be any Window attribute for custom title, so `FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE` can only be set in code.

According to [this article](http://knol.google.com/k/fred-grott/dynamic-status-bar/166jfml0mowlh/27?collectionId=166jfml0mowlh.29#), the best way to draw a title bar is to ignore `FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE` and instead just draw the title bar as part of your main view. This would not only avoid the flashing, but also [problems caused by padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665507/custom-title-bar-without-padding-android).