# How to exclude the title from theme applied to the application?

Tags: android, layout, themes, title

I'm using a theme for my app to set some common layout features.

One of the things I change in this theme is the text style. I change the color and the size of the text in the whole app. Sadly the text in the titlebar is also changed and the result is a somewhat blurry ugly style. I don't know if it is the color or the size of the text

Is it possible to somehow overwrite the style for the title in the theme? Or exclude the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just set the title color separately programatically using the method [setTitleColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setTitleColor(int)) of the Windows class?

So you could overwrite the color you have set in the theme file

Comment: Setting the title color with setTitleColor(Color.WHITE) restores the previous title. It is sad that this is not possible via XML because now I have to add it to every single activity...

Comment: hmm theres a lot of discussion about that topic in the anddev forum:

http://www.anddev.org/my_own_titlebar_backbutton_like_on_the_iphone-t4591.html

maybe the last post on the first page can help you

Answer (score 1):

you could go full screen : [Hiding Title in a Fullscreen mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991764/hiding-title-in-a-fullscreen-mode)

or

have a custom title bar

[Custom title bar without padding (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665507/custom-title-bar-without-padding-android)

Answer (score 0):

Just turn off the title:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Am I missing somthing?

Comment: I like the title. It is a nice and easy way to show the user where he is in the programm