# About the Full Screen And No Titlebar from manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-fullscreen

I want to set my application to full screen view. I got the idea to set it in an individual activity using `FullScreen` and `NoTitlebar`, but i want to set it in my Manifest XML file for the whole application not for each activity... Is this possible?

Help me... Thanks.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

To set your App or any individual activity display in Full Screen mode, insert the code

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

in AndroidManifest.xml, under application or activity tab.

Comment: But is it Work in manifest while adding it in to the Application tag. . . ?

Comment: Now if i want to set the Titlebar but in the center instead of the Default left side. . . is it possible to set it ?

Comment: that wuold be styling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665507/custom-title-bar-without-padding-android

Comment: On ICS (and perhaps all builds) it seems that the Activity theme overrides the Application theme. Adding the same android:theme attribute to the Activity seems to sort this out.

Comment: in lollipop it hides to topbar(notification bar) but cant hide the bottom bar(which contains back btn, recent app and home button).

Answer (score 73):

Another way: add `windowNoTitle` and `windowFullscreen` attributes directly to the theme (you can find `styles.xml` file in `res/values/` directory):

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

in the manifest file, in `application` specify your theme

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: yea, very much thanks to your answer... what's left to say: "you can find the application theme under res/values/styles.xml".... it took me some time to find that there^^   really thanks, man...

Answer (score 10):

If your `Manifest.xml` has the default `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Go to res/values/styles.xml and change

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

And the `ActionBar` is disappeared!

Answer (score 6):

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`in `application` tag.

Individual activities can override the default by setting their own theme attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Try using these theme: **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar**

Mi Style XML file looks like these and works just fine:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an old questions with some old answers. We found that the easiest way to do this in a new project is to edit the res/values/themes/themes.xml file.

**Actionbar:**
Change the parent attribute in the style element to "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar" like this

```
<style name="Theme.WeatherDisplay" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

**Status bar:**
Add the following line under the style element

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

Here is the resulting themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.NameOfApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```