# Sencha touch 2.2.1 logo on top

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm using Sencha Touch 2.2.1, everything working well with Chrome.

But when I do the package and I do test with my phone (Android 4.2.2) I have this contoured part in orange [as you can see on this sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TloJc.png) .

How can I package without this?

Thank you, sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be this? android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

See [this question](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?259817-3.1.0.256-Strange-Android-Titlebar-on-native-Apps/page2) in the sencha forum.

There is a similar option if you are packaging it with PhoneGap, your need to set that in the manifest.xml. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752619/about-the-full-screen-and-no-titlebar-from-manifest).

Good luck, Brad