# How to make my app fullscreen?

Tags: android, android-layout, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

So I have problem in Android. Can't make my layouts fullscreen. I tried changing their themes but nothing happens when I run the app, but in layout preview, it's fullscreen. What to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752619/about-the-full-screen-and-no-titlebar-from-manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Themes can be set inside the styles.xml file directly. And Theme.Holo.Dark is what I guess you are looking for (perhaps you dont want your layout to be black or something :)). There are many more options available you can try. Infact you can even create your own custom theme. :)

Here's the google guide for the same.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: I don't seem to have Theme.Holo.Dark . Is this because of API version I use? An error pops up telling me that this theme can't be found in styles.

Comment: Which API version are you using and can you post the styles the way you are implementing it. Also, just try adding android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" to your activity in the manifiest file.                                                        <activity
        android:name=".login"
        android:label="@string/login"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"/>

Comment: That's exactly the way I tried to put in inside app. My min-sdk is 8, target is 18, but the sdk I'm compiling with is API 10.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this in your Activity (in OnCreate) :

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

?

Comment: Works! How to set black theme? Maybe also with some piece of java code?

Comment: Why did you cancel my answer and switch to another which is not related to your initial question?