# Maintain full screen programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want that screen associated with an activity to be full sized. For this I using this code

```
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

However when doing a drag from touch screen appears bar with state (battery state, wifi state, etc). I using Android version 4.2.2 especially. This point I try to show in the picture below.[image]

How can that be maintained window to full screen programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem occured because your code only executed **once** in `onCreate`. Try using this in your `manifest` instead :

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

For more information :

[About the Full Screen And No Titlebar from manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752619/about-the-full-screen-and-no-titlebar-from-manifest)

Answer (score 0):

METHOD: 1
One way is using Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen value in AndroidManifest.xml file. (Use the appropriate theme name whichever you used in your application)

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

METHOD 2:
Another way is, do this through code in the activity. In your activity do the following before calling setContentView() function

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);        

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```