# How to fit webview to full screen?

Tags: android, webview

I want to my **webview** to fit the screen ,now there is a small empty border        along the **webview** (not coming full screen). how to make my **webview** to fit screen   by using *xml* code [image]

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.fb.jaisonjoseph.facebookbasic.Home_Fragment">

  <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


  <WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think you have used fragment for it. So, try to check padding or margin in activity xml.

Comment: try to use layout_weight & height match_parent of a webview...also put your main_activity .XML file

Comment: i have tried that too @SagarAghara

Comment: yes...then remove margin OR padding in your activity_main that will solve your problem..that is already told by @DheerubhaiBansal

Comment: yes 100% that is padding in your activity_main 16dp check it.

Comment: Actually i am a beginner , can u please provide the code ?

Comment: Post complete code of activity

Comment: Should I remove the padding line ? @Sagar

Comment: yes.all your 4 padding...Left Right Top Bottom

Comment: always happy to Help...(:

Comment: [About the Full Screen And No Titlebar from manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752619/about-the-full-screen-and-no-titlebar-from-manifest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having is most likely because your activity_main probably still has the preset padding that is put in when you first create an Application. This is a code example I made and it worked on full Screen:

[image: MainActivity.java]

[image: activity_main.xml]

Answer (score 2):

You simply add this in your parent layout:

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your WebView code with this one

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"/>
```

I think this code change works for you

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
ndroid:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

in xml file, change activity padding to "0dp"
and change webview to fill_parent or match_parent.