# how to set image view for custom title bar in android

Tags: android, imageview, custom-titlebar

I want to set custom `title bar` to which i want to set `ImageView` as background to the title bar. how to set `ImageView` for **custom title bar** in android. i used:

```
 getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.page_layout);
 requestwindowfeature(Window.CUSTOMTITLEBAR, R.layout.pagelayout);
```

which is not setting the background of the `ImageView`
how do i do it. Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: You can visit this link : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086989/custom-title-with-image

Similar question.