# Android "Header" Text

Tags: java, android, xml, header, manifest

Is there a way to modify an Android app's header programatically? Maybe even adding a custom view with an image in it? I'm talking about the gray bar at the top of an app, whose text can be modified via an app's Mainfest.xml with the label attribute of the activity:

```
<activity android:name=".ProgramTracks" android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Is there some way to, for a lack of a better word, mess with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086989/custom-title-with-image).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom header inside your activitys onCreate().
Write an usual xml layout and call

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
```

where R.layout.window_title is your custom layout.