# title bar not getting full_parent width

Tags: android

I am designing an app which contains header title bar, I am using the following xml for creating header bar. but I am unable to show full width, if i use fill_parent it acts really weird. Any idea or any suggestions how to create a header title bar, increase decrease height. Thanks a lot.

```
window_title.xml lay out below. 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60px"
    android:background="#323331">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/header" 
        android:src="@drawable/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="60px"/>
</LinearLayout>

.java file 

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this if you dont need the defualt title.
Thats all you need.

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Add this after your setContentView. nothing else is required.

Comment: I actually need a header for whole of my app removing the line would remove my header. Any other suggestions.

Comment: it seems you are trying to create a custom title bar. Hmm havent done that much. I usually create a separate xml layout file for the header. And for each xml layout for an activity i add the code <include layout="@layout/app_header_subsection"/>. So it reuses the same xml header layout file.

Comment: ok thats also a good way to do it...Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right, but you should use 9 patch drawable for `ImageView` source. Try, for example this line, and you'll see it works.

```
android:src="@android:drawable/dark_header"
```

`dark_header` it is 9 patch drawable from android sdk. You can find it in `android-sdk/platforms/android-10/data/res/drawable-hdpi` folder.

Update.
Clarifying what I mentioned in a comment. You should also create custom style for your title bar

```
<style name="LargeTitleTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">60dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">
      @android:drawable/dark_header
    </item>
</style>
```

and add it in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity 
  android:name=".TestActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name" 
  android:theme="@style/LargeTitleTheme">
```

Comment: hi use 9 patch drawable for ImageView source, I dint get can you please give some more explanation or code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As I said, your code logic is right, it should work. Also you should provide custom theme to the AndroidManifest. Take look at the [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086989/custom-title-with-image)