# how to customize titlebar with an image in android app?

Tags: android, sdk, titlebar

I would customize the title bar of every activity of my application with an icon and a text. I've tried some ways but they doesn't work. can anybody help me?

this is an example of my code:

```
public class TitleBar extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if ( customTitleSupported ) {
      getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);
    }
    // user can also set color using “Color” and then “Color value constant”
    // myTitleText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
  }
}
```

in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTitleText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="appuntiiiiiii" />

</LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom title with image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086989/custom-title-with-image)

Answer (score 1):

I know it might be overkill for your needs but if you really want something cool you should try implementing ActionBar. It's avalible officialy from API11 but you can implement [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) which looks and works pretty much the same. I'm loving it!

As for your code, there is no ImageView so how could you possible display an image. You need an imageView before your TextView